# wp-includes/comment-template.php:26 - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: debug, notices

I get this notice when debugging my new site.

Does anybody know what this means?
It doesn't break the site but it's just a warning when I switch debug mode on and I would like to solve this issue.

This Notice only shows up when the comments option is available. When you a single post page and the comments have been closed through the dashboard this notice doesn't show up.

This is the 'error' I get:

> NOTICE: wp-includes/comment-template.php:26 - Trying to get property
>   of non-object
>
> require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   include('/themes/XXX/my-templates/template-home.php'), get_footer,
>   locate_template, load_template,
>   require_once('/themes/XXX/footer.php'), wp_footer,
>   do_action('wp_footer'), call_user_func_array, wp_admin_bar_render,
>   do_action_ref_array, call_user_func_array,
>   wp_admin_bar_my_account_item, get_avatar, apply_filters('get_avatar'),
>   call_user_func_array, XXX_remove_dimensions_avatars,
>   get_comment_author

Comment: I'd guess your theme (in "footer.php"?) is calling `get_comment_author()` without checking for `have_comments()` first...

Comment: Syntax errors are off-topic on this site. <a href="http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic">See the help center</a>.

Comment: Thank you @bonger - you're very helpful!

I had used the get_comment_author() function to place the name of the author on the img alt attribute.

Comment: @bonger as an answer please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments, you need to check for `have_comments()` first, before using any of the comment-template functions such as `get_comment_author()`, otherwise they try to call methods on a null comment object, producing PHP warnings.